# Java + Flash => event driven?

Tags: java, flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, blazeds

I've just received a request for an online backgammon game engine. It shouldn't be to hard to make as after all is essentially a chat program that moves pieces instead of showing text messages. I am basically a PHP developer but as I need event driven stuff (no pooling) I assume I could combine a java built core application and a Flash interface. Any suggestions to where should I look for some practical examples and maybe some advices?

Thanks

Comment: Here's a link that looks interesting: http://www.flashmagazine.com/tutorials/detail/getting_across_to_flash_with_java/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also build up the the Flash GUI with [Adobe's Flex SDK](http://www.adobe.com/go/flex/). There are plenty of tutorials in the web for game developing with Flash/Flex. This, for example, is a useful site I found: [Flash Game Development with Flex and ActionScript](http://www.brighthub.com/hubfolio/matthew-casperson/blog/archive/2009/09/03/flash-game-development-with-flex-and-actionscript.aspx)

For the Java backend you could use [BlazeDS](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/BlazeDS) which provides highly scalable remote access and messaging.

> BlazeDS uses two primary exchange
>   patterns between server and client. In
>   the first pattern, the
>   request-response pattern, the client
>   sends a request to the server to be
>   processed. ... The second pattern is
>   the **publish-subscribe** pattern where
>   the server routes published messages
>   to the set of clients that have
>   subscribed to receive them.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible answer may be using red5 or ElectroServer. Client is in Flash and Server plugins are Java.